# How to speed up iterative function call in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, loops, approximation, cdf

In MatLab I have to call the cdf of the t distribution (`tcdf`) **iteratively** (since the next input value depends on the previous output of `tcdf`), which unfortunately slows down my code massively.

```
tic
z = NaN(1e5,1);
z(1) = 1;
x = 2;
for ii = 2:1e5
    x = tcdf(z(ii-1),x);
    z(ii) = z(ii-1)*x;
end
toc

Elapsed time is 4.717087 seconds.
```

*Is there a way to speed this up somehow?*

For comparison:

```
tic
z = randn(1e5,1);
tcdf(z,5);
toc

Elapsed time is 0.091353 seconds.
```

Comment: You could speed up the computation by tabulating `tcdf` for your expected range of inputs. The function call would turn into a table lookup instead (optionally with interpolation to improve precision).

Comment: If you need a 1e5 element vector, then above comment would be a good strategy. Could also tabulate a range and then fit a polynomial rather than a look up table. In the above example (thanks for editing), you might also consider deciding whether the algorithm is converging to a solution and rather than solve a for loop 10,000 time, use a while loop where the condition is if `abs(z(ii) - z(ii-1)) > maxTol` and maxTol is a value you select for "close enough to steady state.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I will go with the tabulate option.

Answer (score 0):

Move the random number generation outside the loop as suggested below

```
numVal = 1e5
z = randn(numVal,1);
for ii = 2:numVal
   z(ii) = z(ii-1) + z(ii);   
end
tcdf(z,5);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the example (which I chose stupidly) is just there to make the point that the next z depends on the previous one and in my I will update the question later.